# Postgres: Update all columns from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I need to update a table from another one, and I need to update all columns, My questions is that, besides list every column in the `SET`, is there a way to update them all like this:

```
update tableA
set * = tableB.*
from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id
```

I tried in psql, it doesn't work.. I have to list every column like this:

```
update tableA
set c1 = tableB.c1, c2 = tableB.c2, ...
from tableB where tableA.id = tableB.id
```

tableB is created use create..like tableA. So they are basically identical. And the reason I'm doing it is that I need load .csv data to temp table tableB and then update tableA based on the new data in tableB. tableA needs to be locked as little as possible and tableA needs to keep integrity. I'm not sure 'delete then insert' would be a good option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could delete and re-insert, if the two tables have the same columns in the same order.  Assuming that all records in tableB match tableA:

```
delete from tableA
    where id in (select id from tableB)

insert into tableA
    select *
    from tableB;
```

(If all records do not match, you could use a temporary table to keep the necessary ids.)

Generally, I oppose doing `insert` without a column list.  In some cases, it is tolerable -- such as when `tableB` was created as a subset from `tableB` using `*`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, actually tableB is created use create..like tableA. So they are basically identical. And the reason I'm doing it is that I need load .csv data to temp table tableB and then update tableA based on the new data in tableB. tableA needs to be locked as little as possible and tableA needs to keep integrity. I'm not sure delete would be a good option? Thanks!

Comment: @odieatla . . . Your comment added a whole bunch of requirements not in the original question.  You might consider asking another question with a much more detailed explanation of what you want to do.  This question seems to be about the superficial desire to not type in a lot of column names into a query, rather than a deeper question about the best way to do something to avoid locking.  By the way, the follow-on question is probably more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com, than for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! I will post it there as well and update my question.

Comment: @odieatla . . . As a note.  You can, of course, update the question.  It is yours.  But if you do so, you may invalidate my answer or make it look silly (which, in fact, just occurred to part of one of my answers on another question).  That can attract downvotes for this answer, which is "not nice" to me (or anyone else who has attempted to answer the question).  What you are looking for is not a small change or clarification to this question (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case and will cause locks but of a different type. Approach that works well for some scenarios.

```
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableA_old;
    ALTER tableA RENAME TO tableA_old;
    ALTER tableB RENAME TO tableA;
COMMIT;
```